# Error while showing updated image after server upload

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components one top bar and Image component

image uploading is working fine after image upload i am calling a function onUploadSuccess in this function when i try to reset it with new uploaded image it is showing error

> Cannot set property 'profileimagepath' of undefined

Image html

```
 <img #profilepicdiv [src]="profileimagepath" width="48" height="48" alt="User" style="border-radius:100px" />
```

Top bar component

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './topbar.component.html',
    selector: 'top-bar',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class TopBarComponent extends AppComponentBase { 
    @Input() profileimagepath: string = "/assets/images/user.png";   
    constructor(
        injector: Injector,
        private _authService: AppAuthService
    ) {
        super(injector);
    }
}
```

Image Component

```
import { TopBarComponent } from '@app/layout/topbar.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'studentimage',
    templateUrl: './studentimage.component.html'
})
export class StudentImageComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit  {
    //@Input() multiple: boolean = false;
    @ViewChild('fileInput') inputEl: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('topBarComponent') topBarComponent: TopBarComponent;      
    saving: boolean = false;
    constructor(
        injector: Injector, private http: Http,
        private _studentService: StudentServiceServiceProxy
    ) {
        super(injector);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
    ngAfterViewInit(): void
    {
        alert('sdf');
    }
    onUploadSuccess() {
        this.notify.success(this.l('Uploaded Successfully'));      
        this.topBarComponent.profileimagepath = /assets/images/newuser.png";        
    }
    onUploadError() {
        this.notify.error(this.l('Please try again'));
    }
}
```

onloadupdate calling

```
 <div [dropzone]="config" (error)="onUploadError($event)" (success)="onUploadSuccess($event)"></div>
```

tried it with viewchild also still same issue

Comment: Did you check if the `this.topBarComponent` is defined when `onUploadSuccess`? Could you show how `onUploadSuccess` is called?

Comment: @Giovane Question updated